# Timer and inputs with React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I try to do a timer in React and it's work but I want the 2 inputs to change the timer name and the seconds.

But it's not working, I can see here on my console the value change but not in my timer...

```
handleChange(event) { console.log(event.target.name); console.log(event.target.value); this.setState({ [event.target.name]: event.target.value }); }

render() {
    return(
      <div>
        <TimerInput libelle={this.state.libelle} seconds={this.state.seconds} handleChange={this.handleChange} />
        <Minuteur libelle={this.state.libelle} seconds={this.state.seconds} handleChange={this.handleChange} />
      </div>
      )
  }
```

Someone can help me ?
Here is the fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/q806zeps/31/

Thank you

Comment: I guess you are receiving `seconds` prop in constructor of `Minuteur`. However you are not updating it as each time input is updated.

Comment: Ya, I think is the problem, you think is possible ? With componentDidMount() {
   this.setState({inputValue: this.props.inputValue});
} but I don't know what to set ??

Comment: Yes, you can update `seconds` state with the help of `componentDidUpdate`

Comment: I try   componentDidUpdate() {
   this.setState({ [event.target.name]: event.target.value });
 } but the app crash.;;;

Comment: In your case it is better to use `componentWillReceiveProps`. However it is not recommended. Here is quick workaround https://jsfiddle.net/q806zeps/36/

Comment: Ok I don't know this function (i'm beginner), I try to set the name of the timer too https://jsfiddle.net/q806zeps/37/ and the name change in real-time but not the timer, do you know why ?

Comment: Please mark a block of code as a block not as inline blocks.